# Run SQL query on MySQL service startup

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, in-memory-tables

I have created HEAP (ram) table on mysql for faster query. But after mysql server restarted, the data in my Heap tables is not loaded.

My normal table name: **products** with id, product_name, status as myisam

**id =>** integer and auto_increment, primary key

**product_name =>** var_char and key(index)

**status =>** boolean

Actual Query:

```
`Select id from products where product_name like "product_name"`
```

I want to increase speed, so i created table with same structure and with named **products_ram** as mysql HEAP table.
I am using this code for fill:

```
insert p_shop.products_ram select * from p_shop.products;
```

But when restart mysql instance HEAP (ram) table data has gone.

I found a document about mysql memory storage :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html

But i can't find what i looking for.

I want to insert/copy my data from products table to products_ram table on mysql server initialization automatically.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: My Operating System : Windows Server 2008 R2
And Mysql : MySQL 5.5

Comment: if you told what operating system this was then we might have a clue as to how your mysqld instance is started.

Comment: Mysql 5.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`init_file`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_file) server option lets you define arbitrary SQL statements to be executed on startup.

---

Edit: Changed the link as the resource has moved on the target site.

Comment: yep, my.ini file located `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini`, I added this line under the `[mysqld]`
`init-file="C:/inetpub/wwwroot/start.sql"`
 and it works! Thank you.

Comment: As I am running on a windows machine as well I had to be aware that the path given in the file must be written with _forward-slashes_ not back-slashes.

Comment: Updated link for MySQL 8.0: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_file