# How to run a MySQL query on every service start?

Tags: mysql, memory-table

I need to run a query to populate a memory table on every MySQL start.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611685/run-sql-query-on-mysql-service-startup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL is able to read statements from [`init_file`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file) on startup.

You'd have to place the following in `my.ini` or `my.cnf` (depending on the OS) file

```
[mysqld] 
init-file="/path/to/your/query/populate_memory_table.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have a system script run after mysql starts.  With systemd in Linux, the following would work:

```
cat > /lib/systemd/system/mysql-preload.service << END
[Unit]
Description=Pre-Load MEMORY tables after MySQL starts
PartOf=mysql.service
After=mysql.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/myuser/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

END
systemctl daemon-reload
```

The script will be run the next time mysql starts or restarts.  Not quite as good as `init_file` because mysql will be available for queries before the MEMORY tables have been populated, but much more flexible.